# Distributed Data Structure across multiple machines with multicast

Tags: c#, windows-services, distributed, multicast

I am looking into the possibility of Distributing a data structure across multiple machines. I would like it to run in a process on each machine, and using (Multicast?) replicate a copy of the full data structure on all of the machines.

Does anyone have any experience in this that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: How big a structure are we talking about?

Comment: not very big, would only have like 5-10 objects in it at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distributed locking is hard -- and you might well need to lock, unless you're reading only. I suggest you take a look at a distributed caching framework like [Microsoft's Velocity](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2&displaylang=en) (which may be renamed as part of Azure now), or the free, open source and very good [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

There are other, pay-for options too -- notably [GemFire](http://www.gemstone.com/products/gemfire) and [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html).

I'd give memcache a go, it works pretty well.

Comment: Only problem with these (i have only used memcached) is that they Shard the data on each server. They don't keep a full copy. So if a server goes down...that shard is lost.

Comment: You can take care of that in your app, but agreed it's an oversight and extra work. Have you seen http://repcached.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: In addition, Gemfire and Coherence explicitly address this, and Microsoft's solution (now AppFabric) appears to have a high availability option too that might meet your needs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790974.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your data into a central database. Then each instance can access it. If you want to modify the data from an instance you shoul implement a mechanism of locking the data in the database. Is this of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Publish the structure through [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) using PUB/SUB sockets and then you can switch between TCP or IP multicast depending on your requirements and network quality.

If your data structure is sufficiently organised you should also be able to send updates to the structure without much issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into Hazelcast which is a Java based solution.

Here is a direct link (1) which talks about some of the internals.

(1) http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#Internals

And there is already a suggestion to use (repcached) memcached which should be easy to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question direction, you should probably learn about [state machine replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine_replication) and then look for implementations of either virtual synchrony or Paxos for your platform, to use as a building block.

Pragmatically, I would advise considering a coordination service such as [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), that would save you a lot of trouble.